# How do i correctly set the filetype txt for *.txt files in vim

Tags: vim, configuration

I am trying to figure out how I am supposed to set the filetext to txt for *.txt files in vim

I was tempted to add a file into the `ftdetect` directory with the content

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead    *.txt     set ft=txt
```

The problem with this approach, however, is that the autocmd is also triggered when I edit `robots.txt`. The default of vim ($VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim) is to detect the robots.txt file and (correctly) set the filetype to *robots* in that case. I don't want to change that.

Additionally, I am not sure why I have to include this autocmd line into the *ftdected* directory. What is the difference to just add the line into my *vimrc* file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `:setf txt` instead of `:set ft=txt`. This way, a previously set filetype (e.g. for `robots.txt`) is kept. From `:help new-filetype`:

> The files in the "ftdetect" directory are used after all the default
>      checks, thus they can overrule a previously detected file type.  But you
>      can also use |:setfiletype| to keep a previously detected filetype.

The benefit of the `ftdetect` directory is that it provides a well-known abstraction, and allows to separate the rules (this is important when you want to publish your filetype plugin for others). You could also put this (enclosed with `:augroup filetypedetect`) into your `~/.vimrc`, but that's not so maintainable and the precedence rules are different.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing up this! I don't know how many times I saw `setf` without realizing that this is different from `set ft=`